# How to query a list of Objects with Firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to query my collections for document Ids, and then get a list of documents.
For Example: 
Collection [Users] -> Documents [001], [002], [003].
Now I want to query in Users for the ids 001 and 003.
Is there an easy way to do this in flutter, or is the recommended way to just just query for 001 and 003 individually ?
[image: e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) for anywhere up to 10 documents.

```
collectionRef.where("country", whereIn: ["USA", "Japan"])
```

If you have more than 10, you can either load them in batches of 10, or so individual calls for each document.

Comment: So there is no way to load them in one query ?
That's disappointing, but still thanks.
If I load them in Batches of 10, will it calculate 10 reads or one ?

Comment: Reading 10 documents results in a charge for 10 **documents** reads. If you're worried about the number of document reads, consider duplicating the necessary user  data under the "other documents" (that you get the user IDs from). Data duplication is the most certain way to reduce the number of individual reads that are required. For a primer on this type of consideration, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).